# Gridview inside a repeater ondataitembound grid view rebinding

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview, dataset, repeater

I've a repeater which has an asp gridview as following :

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rep" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rep_ItemDataBound">
     <ItemTemplate>   
         <asp:GridView ID="grdVw" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
             <Columns>  
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Link" HeaderText="Link" />
             </Columns>
         </asp:GridView>
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

then on page load I bind a `datatable` that contains 20 rows to this repeater:

this is my page load code

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
   //dummy code for testing
            table.Columns.Add("Name");
            table.Columns.Add("Link");

            DataRow row ;
            for (int i = 0; i <20; i++) 
            {
                row = table.NewRow();
                row[0] = "dsadsd";
                row[1] = "text";

                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                ds.Tables.Add(table.Copy());
            }
               rep.DataSource = ds;
                rep.DataBind();
}
```

Then I handle the repeater's `ItemDataBoundevent` like this:

```
protected void rep_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            GridView grdVw = e.Item.FindControl("grdVw") as GridView;
            grdVw.DataSource = table;
            grdVw.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Suprisingly the result is 20 gridviews!! I am thinking this is because `ItemDataBound` fires on each row in the `table`. So in this handler event I bind the table 20 times, but is this logically sound or am I doing something wrong?!

I could easily have a flag to make sure that the data has been bound to the table only once, but what if I've bound a dataset to the repeater? How can I handle this binding to the grid views ?

Comment: If you bound a table to the repeater that has 20 rows, and each row has a gridview in it, then you will without a doubt have 20 grid views.This is doing exactly what you told it to. I imagine that your data for the gridviews needs to come from another variable. What exactly did you expect to happen? what was the desired result?

Comment: I want to bind a dataset to the repeater so I can have gridviews with the number of tables in this dataset, what should I do in data binding, @Pow-Ian is that possible

Comment: I see, so you are not binding based on the number of tables in the data set, you want to bind a gridview in each row that contains the data from each table in the dataset. Your wording is wrong in your question then. Yes it is possible.

Comment: no i was just explaining with an example , as i am expecting when i use data set that the result of grid views will be row no.X tables no. what it's not logic.. Could you please explain how i bind a dataset to a grid view and have gridviews with tables number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line of code:

```
rep.DataSource = ds;
```

to this:

```
rep.DataSource = ds.Tables;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind a repeater with a `dataset` but you need to be careful how you handle the tables inside that set.

this:

```
rep.DataSource = table;
rep.DataBind();
```

Should be:

```
rep.DataSource = {Some Dataset with more than one table};
rep.DataBind();
```

Then in your handler:

```
protected void rep_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        GridView grdVw = e.Item.FindControl("grdVw") as GridView;
        //EDIT: my vb was showing.
        grdVw.DataSource = ((DataTable)e.Item.DataItem).Rows;
        grdVw.DataBind();
    }
}
```

This is not tested but it should work with a little fiddling. What you need to know is that within the repeater you need to be referencing the dataItem of the listItem in order to get a reference to the table. Also Tables are not iEnumerable so make sure you are binding on the rows object.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but it's still not binding tables properly , I've done the following and still returns 20 rows .. this is the binding to gridview statement

grdVw.DataSource = ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem).DataView.Table;

Comment: what are you currently binding? a dataset or a table?

Comment: I've bound a dataset to the repeater and the dataset has 10 tables , the expected result is 10 gridviews not 20 gridviews

Comment: where are you doing the bind for the repeater? it sounds to me like it is being bound twice.

Comment: btw ((Datatable)e.Item.DataItem).Rows; throws the following exception `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'`. so i cast to datarowview and it runs without exception but not as expected

Comment: I am doing it in a `Page_Load` and i debugged to make sure that's executed once and it's

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the DataRowView. I am going to edit again. If you are binding on page load there is no reason for it to be giving you 20 grids.We are missing something.

Comment: and you are getting 20 grids that have 30 rows each?

Comment: try ds.GetList() as the datasource and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I got 20 grid view each one has 20 rows

Comment: what is GetList() function ?, there is no built-in function in datasets has this name

Comment: I looked at something wrong, try the tables property. Something is not adding up here. If you are repeating the items in the dataset, they should be tables, not rowviews.

Comment: thanks for efforts your suggestion was near to @Shai solution :)